# why i am getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am creating small application to get html content from website url using angular cli. i have added imported all required file but i am getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.test.org/publicclass/index.html. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

how we can solve this issue.

script:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';  
 import * as jQuery from 'jquery';   
 import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'; 

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-bodycontent',
  templateUrl: './bodycontent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bodycontent.component.css']
 })  
 export class BodycontentComponent implements OnInit { 
 title = 'app';
 results = '';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient){
 }
 ngOnInit(): void {

 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 this.http.get('https://www.test.org/publictest/index.html').subscribe(html => {
  alert(html);
 });
 } 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web security purpose, all the browsers follow **SOP (Same Origin Policy)**

You can know more about SOP [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

So if you are fetching web service response for your application not abiding these SOP rules, you see these errors in your console.

To Overcome that, you can use **CORS plugin** for chrome. That will solve you problem.

Answer (score 2):

The server at https://www.test.org/publicclass/index.html needs to supply a header that tells browser that your site is allowed to request data from them. it should send a header something like the following with response-

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
```

then you would be able to use resource from that url into your page.

alternately, if its only for your local environment there are browser extension available (for almost all major browsers) that help bypass this restriction. you can use them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i am new in angular cli so can you tell me exactly what i want to do.

Comment: this is not specific to angular, I would suggest you go through the documentation here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: finaly you are telling i want to run this script in firefox rite because that browser only support?

Comment: which script? the target server needs to set that header.

Comment: That documentation is applicable to HTTP web standards in general, not only firefox

Comment: ya..i am not getting error: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in firefox but html content is not coming in alert. can you edit my code?